# SWRevealViewController how to go back to previous ViewController after performing SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My company's app has pages that can be reached during normal navigating using **normal** `push segues` and in the same time it can be accessed from the **side menu** using `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController`

in the normal push segue i can go back to the previous page by doing this :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but this won't work in the second case as i am pushing SWReveal push to that page using a **new** `navigation controller` so it won't pop , but i want it to go back to the previous page **before** selecting that new page from the menu

in the first case i just push **directly** to the new page
in the second case i push to a **navigation controller** that it's root is the new page

[image]

## 1 is the side menu itself

## 2 is the profile view controller that can get to the messages ViewController using the normal push segue in #4

## 3 the SWReveal push segue to the messages navigation controller

i want the back button to pop to the previous page before clicking messages from the side menu

i hope i made it clear

Comment: show ur storyboard scene

Comment: done i added an image and more description

Comment: how do u create the segue is present or push

Comment: i mentioned it before it's push :)

Comment: what i understood from your above explanation is : after SWReveal push segue from 1st (menu screen) to 4th screen! On pressing back button of 4th screen, you wish to open 2nd Screen & not Menu. Right? @Alshcompiler

Answer (score 0):

I used SWRevealViewController before in iOS/swift project and I didn't face this problem,

I connected all the view controllers the I'd need a navigation for with a navigation controller and segues from the view controller itself to the target view controller

[Storyboard three connected view controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYZxo.jpg)

---

I used `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUE_IDENTFIRE, sender: nil)` for normal segue

---

and `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` for previous view controller

Comment: This is not what i asked